# How do I create a simple video effect filter for DirectShow or DMO?

Tags: filter, directshow, dmo

How do I create a simple video effect filter for DirectShow or DMO?

What I need is simple - a tutorial or tutorials on how to create simple filter (like a brightness/contrast adjustment filter or any other pixel-per-pixel kind of filter) for filtering Direct Show Video astream (so I want to have a graph like "my Web Kamera" -> "My photoshop like filter" -> "rendering (or saving to file)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is probably a DirectShow transform filter, there is a sample filter in the Windows SDK; EZRGB24 Filter Sample

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375468(VS.85).aspx